# Why is the accepted summation multiplication formula what it is?

Tags: summation

$\sum_{n=0}^3 n = 6$ and $6^2 = 36$

I know the formula is $$\left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \right)\left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n (a_n)(b_{n-k})$$

So: $$\left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \right)^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n (a_n)(a_{n-k})$$

But the formula shows a different story, like:  $(a_0)(a_0) + (a_1)(a_1) + (a_1)(a_0) + (a_2)(a_2) + \ldots$ equals 0(0) + 1(1) + 1(0) + 2(2) + 2(1) + 2(0) + 3(3) + 3(2) + 3(1) + 3(0) still doesn’t equal 36 it equals 25, so am I getting the formula wrong or what?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your calculator is doing $$\sum_{n=0}^3 n^2,$$ not $$\left(\sum_{n=0}^3 n\right)^2.$$

You seem to rely on your calculator too much, and lack appropriate calculating abilities. You should have realized that $14$ is $1+4+9$.

Comment: You are missing some terms. You have $2(1)$ but not $1(2)$, which are both required. Similarly, $3(1), 1(3)$ &c.

Comment: Thank you very much, that’s what I was confused about